# Can I take nootropics if I was on seizure medication 5+ years ago?

Tags: seizure, concentration, alertness-level, side-effects, nootropic-smart-drugs

So as a college student, we need to perform mentally demanding work and I recently found out about "all natural" pills that can increase focus and alertness. So I decided I am going to try them to see how they work. I tried another nootropic brand (Optimind) and did not feel like it was working after trying it 4 times. However, the bottle of 60 pills I received for a different brand said:

> Use cautiously in patients with a history of seizures.

I have been completely off my seizure medication for over 5 years now. Do I still fit into this category of having a "history of seizures" or does this no longer apply to me?

This is the nootropic product page for reference: [http://www.amazon.com/NeuroEnhance-Function-Supplement-Supports-Cognitive/dp/B019TH6SSM/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019TH6SSM)

Comment: Did you ever have any seizures? This may seem dumb, but the question only said you had been on the seizure meds.

Comment: Yeah I had it since a young age apparently and exclusively while sleeping at night. I used to wake up with strong headaches. The medication was taken for several years and I came out of it completely around 5 years ago. It's been so long, so I can't remember when I stopped taking the medication. Have not seen any symptoms of seizures at all since then, so I'm wondering if that condition is relevant at this point or not.

Answer (score 2):

**You would have a history of seizures even if they occured 5 years ago.** Histories of disorders go back decades(your lifetime), especially if there is risk of recurrence as in cancer or seizures.

[Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019TH6SSM)

> **Use cautiously** in patients with history of seizures, based on reports
>   of seizures due to gingko seed ingestion.

Since you need to use it cautiously know that the FDA didnt evaulate any of their statements by the manufacturers own admission in the legal part of the label.

Gingko may have links to seizures as the conpany said. Further references on that are below:

- [ncbi.nlm.nih.com](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16419414)
- [acs.org](http://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/pressroom/presspacs/2010/acs-presspac-april-14-2010/ginkgo-herbal-medicines-may-increase-seizures-in-people-with-epiy.html)

***Knowing this and based on your risk factors you should consult a physician to answer your questions especially for possible other medications and how pertinent your history of seizures is.***

Comment: It just feels like an inconvenience to contact a doctor whom I haven't spoken to for over 5 years.

Comment: I thought you were trying to advertise something on Amazon, and then I noticed you were citing the warning label. :P

Answer (score 0):

It applies to you. You have a history of seizures for the rest of your life.

Check out this [basic Medical History for Epilepsy list of questions](http://www.uofmhealth.org/health-library/hw108757) as a reference.